# GridDb gsadm incorrect password

Tags: griddb

Trying to install GridDb described in here [here](https://medium.com/griddb/griddb-quickstart-9e4a47be5849)

It says; *Set the password for the default admin user (we’ll use the very-insecure password, “admin")*. So I did `gs_passwd` admin and set password admin too

```
-bash-4.2$ gs_passwd admin
Password: 
Retype password:
```

But `gsadm` is always fails with admin/admin

```
-bash-4.2$ sudo su - gsadm

[sudo] password for gsadm: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for gsadm: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for gsadm: 
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to `sudo su` anymore, just gs_startnode worked fine!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).